# Trying to copy over data to a dashboard and it is not copying over and I am not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I have an advanced filter filtering data in a database based on dates. I am trying to get the results to show up on a dashboard but it is not copying over. My code is below.

```
Dim PLRow As Long
Dim LastTransRow As Long
Dim AcctRow As Long
With Sheet1
.Range("F52:J99999").ClearContents
LastTransRow = Sheet6.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet6.Range("AK3:AP99999").ClearContents
Sheet6.Range("A2:F" & LastTransRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheet6.Range("AA2:AC3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet6.Range("AK2:AP99999"), Unique:=True
If Sheet6.Range("AK3").End(xlUp).Row < 3 Then GoTo NoResults
PLRow = 52 'Set Intial Profit and Loss Row

'Add in Income Accounts
For AcctRow = 3 To 17
    If Sheet6.Range("M" & AcctRow).Value = "Income" And Sheet6.Range("N" & AcctRow).Value <> 0 Then
        .Range("H" & PLRow).Value = Sheet6.Range("L" & AcctRow).Value 'Account Name
        .Range("I" & PLRow).Value = Sheet6.Range("N" & AcctRow).Value 'Account Value
        PLRow = PLRow + 1
    End If
Next AcctRow
.Range("G" & PLRow).Value = "Total Income"
.Range("I" & PLRow).Value = Sheet6.Range("TotIncome").Value
PLRow = PLRow + 2
```

What do I need to change in my code so that it will copy over from Sheet 6 to Sheet 1?

Comment: `If Sheet6.Range("AK3").End(xlUp).Row < 3 Then GoTo NoResults` - that will always be true.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. That fixed my problem